# 2 Custom Post Types One shared Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have two custom Post types (series, and audio) with one shared custom taxonomy. One Series post will have multiple related audio posts. I am trying to relate them by a category. I want to show all of the related audio posts on the series page. I have tried looping through the taxonomy but I either get a list of series posts or all of the series and audio posts. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
//get the post's Tax
  $custom_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'series_taxonomy');

  if( $custom_terms ){

      // going to hold our tax_query params
      $tax_query = array();

      // add the relation parameter (not sure if it causes trouble if only 1 term so what the heck)
      if( count( $custom_terms > 1 ) )
          $tax_query['relation'] = 'OR' ;

      // loop through venus and build a tax query
      foreach( $custom_terms as $custom_term ) {

          $tax_query[] = array(
              'taxonomy' => 'series_taxonomy',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
          );

      }

      // put all the WP_Query args together
      $args = array( 'post_type' => 'sermon',
                      'posts_per_page' => 5,
                      'tax_query' => $tax_query );

      // finally run the query
      $loop = new WP_Query($args);

      if( $loop->have_posts() ) {

          while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

          <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></div></a>
          <?php

          endwhile;

      }

      wp_reset_query();

  }?>
```